# Port Forwarding between 2 hosts in VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, iptables, port-forwarding, tunnel

I'm having some problems while trying to set port forwarding rules on a Ubuntu machine. I'll explain my situation..

I have a Raspberry in my local home's network and I have a webserver installed on it. I would like to connect to it while I'm away from home. Unfortunately, my ISP doesn't provide by defualt a static IP. I have to pay €8 a month for it (pretty expensive for me). I can't configure a dynamic DNS on my router  because my ISP has a double NAT, so I decided to configure a VPN server on a "cheap" VPS (with static IP). I tried OpenVPN but that was too complex for me, so I switched to Tinc, and I managed to get it working as I wanted.

On the VPN, the VPS has IP `10.0.0.1` and the Raspberry has IP `10.0.0.2`. I tried to ping between them and it worked.

Now, I want to set some port-forwarding rules on the VPS so I can SSH to my Raspberry (port 22) and also access to the webpage (port 80) using the IP of the VPS. How can I manage to get it working? I tried to use iptables, but without any success...

Comment: the VPS has 10.0.0.1, the raspberry has 0.2. the vps and the raspberry can ping each other so they should also be able to ssh into each other too. I guess you are trying to connect a third client to your vpn as 10.0.0.3 and try to connect to your pi using `ssh pi@10.0.0.2` but it might be, that your server does not allow different clients to see each other (i dont know tinc). Perhaps you need to allow ipv4 forwarding in `/etc/sysctl.conf`. I use openvpn and to be able to access services between my vpn-clients i never had to do any iptables rules but server-config adjustments.

Comment: What I want to achieve is a little different. The VPS has a public static IP. Let's suppose that the VPS' IP is `185.25.207.100`. Between the Raspberry and the VPS there's a VPN connection. The VPS has the IP `10.0.0.1` and the Raspberry has the IP `10.0.0.2`. On the Raspberry there's a webserver (port 80). So, I want to connect to the webpage using the IP of the VPS. In other terms, typing `185.25.207.100:80` on the browser I access to the webpage of the Raspberry. I also want to to a similar thing for SSH (maybe using a different port, like `8022`).

Comment: Anyway, I found a guide that explained how to do what I wanted for the web server part. ([> Guide link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-forward-ports-through-a-linux-gateway-with-iptables)). Now, if I go to `185.25.207.100:80` using a web browser I access to the webpage of the Raspberry. I want to do a similar thing for SSH, which I suppose that has different configurations comparing to what I did for the webserver's port forwarding. For example, I want to connect to the Raspberry using port 8022, so i will use `185.25.207.100:8022`.

Comment: ah okay, now i understand. yes, NAT in conjunction with iptables should be the way to go. you could also try to just forward all input traffic at wan port to your vpn device instead of limiting to specified ports.

Comment: Actl. i cannot test these settings because i am in holidays, but if i remember well with these commands your vps should route your vpn to the internet and vice versa (in this case eth0 is the internet facing device and tun0 the vpn facing device: `sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`
`sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun0  -j ACCEPT`
`sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT`

Comment: First of all, thanks for your responses, I really appreciate it. I'm really interested in the the idea of forwarding the whole traffic, but I have some questions about it. If I forward port 22, how will I be able to SSH to my VPS? Anyway, I tried your commands, adapting them for my devices, but It didn't work. I have a question: if I use the guide of my last comment adapting it for SSH, do you think that I have to change other parameters in the commands? Sorry but I don't know much about protocols.

Comment: If you are going to translate a ssh port that both ssh-daemon use i guess you will have problems contacting to your vps, indeed. The thing is, you translate incoming packets on a specified device wan0 to vpn0. So if you try to connect to port 22 from wan0 you will be redirected to vpn0 but if you connect to port 22 from vpn0 it should work. In the end it might be better to just translate specified ports from specified devices to specified devices and drop the rest. Also it is a good idea to change port 22 to something else + make use of `fail2ban` against brute-force attacks etc.